# WO/2008/130257 Diesel Engine Tuningboxes

Tags: wo2012120312a1

actually i am astonished to read about that patent. Since 2003 mostlikely Tuningboxes/Powerboxes are available on the market. The way they are operating is exactly the same as described in

Pub. No.:       WO/2008/130257
International Application No.:      PCT/PL2008/000021
Publication Date:   30.10.2008
International Filing Date:  10.03.2008
IPC: B60R 25/042 (2013.01), F02D 41/24 (2006.01), F02M 59/36 (2006.01)

It is nicely described and does not bring any attention of Tuningboxes where bunch of manufactures where already doing this before the patent application time.
Not sure, if this has been checked correctly by patent authority.

According to Google Patent search there are already some legal events:
http://www.google.com/patents/WO2008130257A1?cl=en

Does anyone know, where to look those events up?

Secondly, since it is NO innovation and the usual procedure as tons of other Tuningbox manufactures is this patent still valid?

Can all those guys who where doing business since ever fear about beeing sued?

Since this unit is handling only 1 Channel, how about using 2 Channel. Will it still infringe this patent?

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Application does not equal patent. This is not yet a patent and may never become one.

Answer (score 1):

The legal events were just the publication of two European patent applications that were branched off this international patent application. There is nothing in the google patents page that indicates any patent in any country was ever granted based on these applications.

Comment: Correct. According to EPregister, the application never even entered the European phase and is deemed to be withdrawn. So nothing to discuss here, really.